# TensorFlow error : TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable - I can not find where is the problem

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

first I am a greenhorn in ML, so its probably a stupid mistake :)

I downloaded this dataset:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/muhammadtalharasool/simple-gender-classification

Turned to variable gender_2

Use OneHotCode:

```
gender_one_hot_2 = pd.get_dummies(gender_2)
gender_one_hot_2.head()

gender_one_HOT = gender_one_hot_2.drop("Unnamed: 9", axis = 1)
```

Normalized the data:

```
cf = make_column_transformer((MinMaxScaler(), [' Age', ' Height (cm)', ' Weight (kg)']),
                             (OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown= "ignore"),[' Occupation_ Accountant', ' Occupation_ Analyst',
       ' Occupation_ Architect', ' Occupation_ Business Analyst',
       ' Occupation_ Business Consultant', ' Occupation_ CEO',
       ' Occupation_ Doctor', ' Occupation_ Engineer',
       ' Occupation_ Graphic Designer', ' Occupation_ IT Manager',
       ' Occupation_ Lawyer', ' Occupation_ Marketing Specialist',
       ' Occupation_ Nurse', ' Occupation_ Project Manager',
       ' Occupation_ Sales Representative', ' Occupation_ Software Engineer',
       ' Occupation_ Teacher', ' Occupation_ Writer', ' Occupation_Accountant',
       ' Occupation_Analyst', ' Occupation_Architect',
       ' Occupation_Business Analyst', ' Occupation_CEO', ' Occupation_Doctor',
       ' Occupation_Engineer', ' Occupation_Graphic Designer',
       ' Occupation_IT Manager', ' Occupation_Lawyer',
       ' Occupation_Marketing Specialist', ' Occupation_Nurse',
       ' Occupation_Project Manager', ' Occupation_Sales Representative',
       ' Occupation_Software Developer', ' Occupation_Teacher',
       ' Occupation_Writer', " Education Level_ Associate's Degree",
       " Education Level_ Bachelor's Degree",
       ' Education Level_ Doctorate Degree',
       " Education Level_ Master's Degree" ,
       " Education Level_Associate's Degree",
       " Education Level_Bachelor's Degree",
       ' Education Level_Doctorate Degree', " Education Level_Master's Degree",
       ' Marital Status_ Divorced', ' Marital Status_ Married',
       ' Marital Status_ Single', ' Marital Status_ Widowed',
       ' Marital Status_Divorced', ' Marital Status_Married',
       ' Marital Status_Single', ' Favorite Color_ Black',
       ' Favorite Color_ Blue', ' Favorite Color_ Green',
       ' Favorite Color_ Grey', ' Favorite Color_ Orange',
       ' Favorite Color_ Pink', ' Favorite Color_ Purple',
       ' Favorite Color_ Red', ' Favorite Color_ Yellow',
       ' Favorite Color_Black', ' Favorite Color_Blue',
       ' Favorite Color_Green', ' Favorite Color_Grey',
       ' Favorite Color_Orange', ' Favorite Color_Pink',
       ' Favorite Color_Purple', ' Favorite Color_Red',
       ' Favorite Color_Yellow'])
)
X = gender_one_HOT.drop(" Income (USD)", axis = 1)
y = gender_one_HOT[" Income (USD)"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)

cf.fit(X_train)

X_train_normal_2 = cf.transform(X_train)
X_test_normal_2 = cf.transform(X_test)
```

and then I inserted to the NN:

```
tf.random.set_seed(42)

model_gender_2 = tf.keras.Sequential(tf.keras.layers.Dense(60 ,input_shape=139),
                                     tf.keras.layers.Dense(30),
                                     tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
                                     )

model_gender_2.compile(loss = tf.keras.losess.mae,
                       optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.01),
                       metrics = ["mae"])
model_gender_2.fit(X_train_normal_2, y_train, epochs = 120)


but I got this output: 

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-e0b5ab8c49e8> in <module>
      1 tf.random.set_seed(42)
      2 
----> 3 model_gender_2 = tf.keras.Sequential(tf.keras.layers.Dense(60 ,input_shape=139),
      4                                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(30),
      5                                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __init__(self, trainable, name, dtype, dynamic, **kwargs)
    450                 else:
    451                     batch_size = None
--> 452                 batch_input_shape = (batch_size,) + tuple(kwargs["input_shape"])
    453             self._batch_input_shape = batch_input_shape
    454 

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Actualy I can not find the error I tried change the input on the first layer but it did not work:/

I tried inserting different input shapes but it did not work

I tried to change input shape of the first layer to 139 - which should be the right one but still does not work

Comment: The input shape is always a tuple, it cannot be a plain integer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the function `tf.keras.Sequential`. It expects a list of layers rather than each layer as an argument. So, the way you're passing the input is wrong. Try doing this:

```
model_gender_2 = tf.keras.Sequential()
model_gender_2.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(60, input_shape=(139,))
model_gender_2.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(30)
model_gender_2.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
```

Or this

```
model_gender_2 = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(60, input_shape=139),
                                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(30),
                                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])
```

Comment: Actualy it does not work:

Comment: the problem is still the same "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Comment: It could be due to different tensorflow version. I ran it and worked fine for me. You can also update 139 to `(139,)` that should work. I have tenforflow `2.11.0`

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I replaced the input_shape it works, anyway I tried this yesterday and it did not work so that was the reason why I insert the input_shape. It looks like TensorFlow trolling me all the time :))

`model_gender_2 = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(60), tf.keras.layers.Dense(30), tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])`